# Troubleshooting Python Regex Pattern

Tags: python, regex, string

For a larger Python program I am developing, I am trying to write a method which removes all sections of a string eveloped by two different tags; a start tag `r'{foo}'` and an end tag `r'{/foo}'`. If it were to run successfully, it would take a string such as:

```
r'stay {foo}leave{/foo} stay {foo} leave {/foo} stay'
```

and return string:

```
r'stay  stay  stay'.
```

Furthermore, it wouldn't do anything if the sections were incomplete. In other words, if you gave the program string:

```
r'stay {/foo} {foo} leave {/foo} {foo} stay'
```

it would return string:

```
r'stay {/foo}  {foo} stay'
```

which is the intended behavior.

To resolve this issue, I turned to the python re library to create a regular expression that would do this for me. The closest thing I've had to success is with the regex pattern `r'{foo}.*{/foo}'` which only works, if and only if, there is one tagged section within the string. For example, using the pattern `r'{foo}.*{/foo}'` with string:

```
r'stay {foo} leave {/foo} stay'
```

would return `r'stay  stay'` as expected, but if I do the same with the first example:

```
r'stay {foo}leave{/foo} stay {foo} leave {/foo} stay'
```

I'd get `r'stay  stay'` instead of the expected result `r'stay  stay  stay'`.
While I feel like I am so close to figuring this out, my understanding of regular expressions is far from advanced. I would appreciate some help troubleshooting the right regex pattern for this scenario.

Comment: Your regex is "greedy", changing `.*` to `.*?` will change that and cause it to stop matching at the first `{/foo}` instead of the last it can find. Having said that, have you considered what should happen for something like `'{foo} {foo} test {/foo} {/foo}'`? And will there be more tags than just `foo`, that can intermix in various ways? Matching potentially nested paired markers is not a task regex is typically ideal for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the "non-greedy" (a.k.a. "minimal") version of the star operator, which is `*?`. Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

Hence, change your pattern to: `r'{foo}.*?{/foo}'`

Comment: Wow, I was really that close lol. Now I know what 'minimal' means in the context of regex